# How to sort vuetify v-data-table by item value rather than template slot displayed value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` that has an alphanumeric ID with JSON key name aid (ie, AZ-0001). I also have a field in the JSON array called id which is basically just the numeric version (ie, 0001). When I sort the datatable it always puts the A's first and is not really numerically sorting which is what I want so I created a v-slot template to adjust what is displayed so that ID is the item slot and AID is whats actually displayed in the `v-slot` template. However, even doing this when pressing the sort icon for ID column it still sorts alphanumerically on what is actually being displayed (AID) so A's first rather than numerically just going by id which is the actual value for that column. I have another column similar to this that displays the date as Calendar year or Fiscal Year (ie, CY2022 and FY2022) so I run into a similar issue with this alphanumberic sorting doing alphabetically. So the simple example I show below I am hoping to use it for multiple fields. I plan to use the solution to this problem on another column I am running into a similar issue that I did not include in this example. My code is as follows:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headerset"
  :items="filteredData"
  :search="searchTable"
  height="inherit"
  :loading="loading"
  loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
  style="cursor: pointer"
>
  <template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
    {{ item.aid }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to explain [@Takezoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6295960) answer.

Assume you have a `v-data-table`:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="5"
></v-data-table>
```

The solution is to place custom sort function into your `headers` array. This way, by example:

```js
data () {
  return {
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Identifier',
        value: 'id',
        sort: this.customIdSort,
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      ...
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        id: 'AZ-0001',
        calories: 159,
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 'AB-0004',
        calories: 237,
        ...
      },
      ...
   ]
 }
}
```

Then you need to define this custom function. Unfortunately, I'm not clearly understand your sort logic, but you can write your own if this will not suit you:

```js
methods: {
  customIdSort(a, b) {
    let aId = a.substring(3)
    let bId = b.substring(3)
    return aId.localeCompare(bId)
  }
}
```

[Test this solution at CodePen.](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/ZEogjZj)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer however jus to understand how the custom sort function works what does the parameters a and b represent?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88, `a` and `b` are the comparable values of a column (identifiers in this case). Sorting function just compares two values on each iteration of internal sorting algorithm and expecting result `<0` (a before b), `0` (a equals to b) or `>0` (a > b).  That's why you can use native `localeCompare` function in this case. You can also use `console.log` for both parameters for a better understanding

Comment: One last question. Say the example above was for item.DateColumn and in the v-slot it was a formatted date such as {{FormattedDate}} which converts the column DateColumn values to say FY2022, or CY2021. Would the customSort function parameters for a and b represents the v-slot values or the actual item value for that row? I will do some testing. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to make a sort function like this but gets an error saying localeCompare is not a function.                 customDateSort(a, b) {
                    let aDate = new Date(a)
                    aDate = aDate.getTime()
                    let bDate = new Date(b)
                    bDate = bDate.getTime()
                    
                    return aDate.localeCompare(bDate)
                },

Comment: So I am realizing localeCompare compares stings so i convert it to String(NewDate()) and its good to go! I did notice that adding these custom sorts seems to sort my data by default initially on load. Anyway to keep it unsorted or make it start in descended order so the largest ID is on top?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88, to make initial sort you can use **sort-by** and **sort-desc** props. Example: `:sort-by="['id']"` `:sort-desc="[false]"`

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 customSort function parameters are represents values of related header, not a printed v-slot. Feel free to test it in a CodePen I provided. **localeCompare** is a vanilla JS function in a String class, [see docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a sort function in your headers that specify how your items should be sorted for a given column.

From there you should be able to implement the sort function you want.

```
export interface DataTableHeader<T extends any = any> {
  text: string
  value: string
  align?: 'start' | 'center' | 'end'
  sortable?: boolean
  filterable?: boolean
  groupable?: boolean
  divider?: boolean
  class?: string | string[]
  cellClass?: string | string[]
  width?: string | number
  filter?: (value: any, search: string | null, item: any) => boolean
  sort?: DataTableCompareFunction<T>
}
```

Comment: We use the vue cdn for building our application. How does this fit in there? Never used extends.

Comment: @qiuzman this is the interface type for the header, showing all possible options that are available to you. Think of this as *very* detailed documentation, once you learn little bit of Typescript, it becomes invaluable tool. Almost all libs/packages now days are written in Typescript and provide "types" such as this. This is from: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/e8cf8866d327aaac5d7dcff1ac5e3ea4b1af5c85/packages/vuetify/types/index.d.ts#L282 

"T" part of `T extends any = any` is your data type you can provide via JSDoc or TS, to get better completion, error checking, etc.

Comment: @Russ Deneychuk thanks for the info as I was still confused what this response indicated as I am still new to front end development. I have not made the jump to Typescript yet and keep questioning if worth it. but sounds like it is for things of this nature.

Comment: @qiuzman It probably is, I know when I was starting out, every so often I would have a bug, where cause was simple typo, or data coming in from api is different than expected. Typescript would catch all that.

Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQFQO4gHIFcC2AjAUwCcIYBeGACjgC4YxdCiAaGPOh-YgSg8ePIA+GAG8iBKFiJh4MANRsAvgChloSCAA2BAHSaQAc2pI0mfiUoBGVgGZu3GAHpHMDCCI44mmMgDKa8AgtXX0jRBR0bC4LaxgAcgBWACY4+ycXNw8vH18YBAkCYCgASzADGFQicHKoAE8ABwIYEAAzGAA3Lywm+qr24vyEVWcYAAEoCABaYoMwdwIAjW09Q2MIs2iIK1YAbTikhLg4gF00kd9inCxNOCgCBBgAKVzJvJACUjnYYDhxeDwQFhYHVGs02ghbnAYL0QP1BkA